# Using ssh how to remotely check to see if python3 or any other given package is installed on my server?

Tags: bash, ssh, grep

I have an Ubuntu server with ssh key already set up on it. Without having to log in, and from a bash script that will run on my local machine I want to check if a given package is already installed on the server. The desired output is a boolean 0 or 1. The command I have come up with so far is:

```
$ ssh root@myserver 'dpkg-query -W python3 | grep -c "no package found"'
0
```

This command outputs 0 for both packages that are installed and those that are not.

I move back one step and try to implement this on my local machine. Something happens that looks strange to me.

when I try:

```
$ dpkg-query -W python
dpkg-query: no packages found matching python
```

when I try:

```
$ dpkg-query -W python3
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Architecture Description
+++-==============-==============-============-=========================================================================
ii  python3        3.8.2-0ubuntu2 amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
```

This is fine and so for the "python" case I expect to pipe this output to grep and check if a string like "no packages found" exist inside it. I run the following and suprisingly get 0 returned.

```
$ dpkg-query -W python | grep -c "no packages found"
dpkg-query: no packages found matching python
0
```

Shouldn't this return a single line 1? Why the command output is still shown on the terminal while I have piped it to another command? I assume that the output is never piped to grep because I can successfully run:

```
$ echo "dpkg-query: no packages found matching python" | grep -c "no packages found"
1
```

Please explain why is this happening and forgive me if I am asking a trivial question because I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a pretty universal rule: error messages from commands are written to stderr, not stdout. Pipe redirects only stdout to another command; stderr remains connected to the terminal. `dpkg-query: no packages found matching python` is an error message, so it is written to stderr (ie. to the terminal), and an empty output on stdout is piped to `grep`, therefore `grep` returns 0.

If you want both stdout and stderr be piped to `grep`, you should use something like

```
dpkg-query -W python 2>&1 | grep -c "no packages found"
```

The ssh version of the command you included in your question also will **not** work as you described. You should also include `2>&1` in it as in the command above, otherwise it will work exactly as the local version - unless your ssh client (or server on the remote machine) is somehow configured to redirect stderr to stdout, but this is **not** a standard configuration. In my case the ssh version behaves exactly as the local version.

But instead of piping the output of `dpkg-query` through `grep` (which can be locale dependent and thus unreliable), you can just use the return code from `dpkg-query` command. It will be 0 if the package is installed, or 1 if not. So you can use something like

```
dpkg-query -W python >& /dev/null ; echo $?
```

`>& /dev/null` is there to get rid of any output at all from `dpkg-query` (both stdout and stderr), as we are interested only in the return code (`$?`). Note: `>&` works in `bash`. If you want it to use in `sh` (for example in a script), you should use this instead:

```
dpkg-query -W python >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?
```

Comment: Good catch raj. I stupidly forgot about that :-D

Comment: Ah what a great answer. You took me out of a big head ache. I didn't really know where to look for the issue,

Comment: One final question. How do we recognize if the output shown on terminal is from stderr or stdout?

Comment: @PouJa There is no way. You can only find it out by redirecting either stdout or stderr and watch if anything appears on the terminal. Or by looking at the program source code :)

Comment: @PouJa But generally if a program prints something that starts with program name followed by a colon, then it is probably an error message and as such it is written to stderr.